# How to create a Module in Root Directory in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-7

I want to work with [Laravel-Modules](https://nwidart.com/laravel-modules)

I can create Modules under Module Folder. But I want to create a Module in the Root directory and while it will run, the Root Module will run first.

Is it possible?
If possible then give me the way.

I have tried with

```
"psr-4": {
    "App\\": "app/",
    "Modules\\": "/"
}
```

But it is giving me an Error:

> Directory name must not be empty.

Comment: What is giving you that error? Definitely not `composer`.

Comment: Error solved.
But Modules are not creating in the root directory.

Comment: then you should post a solution as regular answer so others will know and then create another question about problems with modules creation

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
"psr-4": {
  "App\\": "app/",
  "Modules\\": "Modules/"
}
```

Comment: I want to create a Module in the Root directory.

Comment: yes brother this is a refrence of module directory on root now you can make multiple modules in this folder